# Storing processed results of connection in RDBMS

Tags: database, data-structures, rdbms

A csv file contains following two column : admission_number, project_name.
The relationship between two entities are many to many relationships : a specific admission_number can work over multiple projects. A specific project may have multiple admission_number.

Data will be like as follows and initially there are '1000 milion' rows and data will keep on updating on daily basis in this table will go upto 1300 milion rows.

```
admission_number,project_name
1234567890,ABC1234567
1234567890,ABC1234568
1234567891,ABC1234569
1234567892,ABC1234569
1234567893,ABC1234570
1234567894,ABC1234567
1234567895,ABC1234567
```

For a specific admission number(lets say 1234567890), i want to know all the admission_number who are working on the same projects (ABC1234567,ABC1234568). The output of above query will be
1234567894,1234567895.

Explanation : Since for admission number '1234567890', projects name are 'ABC1234567' and 'ABC1234568'. On these two projects other 'admission_number' are working as '1234567894','1234567895'

I came up with two solutions, To store the data,RDBMS will be used.

Approach 1 : By using two retrieval query : First query shall return all the projcects_name for a specific 'admission_number' and the second query will retrun all the admission_number for 'project_name'.

```
select admission_number from table where project_name IN (select project_name from table where admission_number='ABC1234567'.
```

Approach 2 : In this approach, before going for loading i am preprocessing the results and directly results is storing in database. I am only storing all the connected 'admission_number'.

Eg. For project_name 'ABC1234567', these 3 admission_number '1234567890','1234567894', '1234567895' are working. I want to store all connected admission_number in table with two columns (number,connected_number) like ('1234567890','1234567894'),('1234567890','1234567895'), ('1234567894','1234567895'), and query will work on both columns (number and connected_number).

But in this approach there will be many rows means if a specifc project_name 'p', there are n 'admission_number' than total number of rows will be n(n-1)/2

How can i store all the connected admission_number in RDBMS? Loading of data can be slow, but retrieval should be fast.

Answer (score 1):

Do not optimize the data structure. It would only cause problems.

Create a simple table with two columns for both ID and [create index](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp) for both columns.

The RDBMS will build and maintain [an index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) of the column values, which will enable fast lookup for a specific record.

Comment: @Juraj...To prevent duplicate inserting i am creating primary key for both columns. I am creating index on 'admission_number' and range partitioning on 'project_name'. 'project_name' will be bigint value having 10 digit value(max_value:3*e9)..Is it ok?

Comment: @user752590, you can create unique index for two columns so serial id is not necessary. yes, partitioning on project_name is a good idea. I didn't mention it in the answer because not all RDMBS support it. the point is you can fine tune the RDBMS settings without complicating the data structure.

Comment: @user752590 or make the pair of columns a primary key. we do it for N:N association tables like this one